# Ability to click on filenames in cygwin console to launch file

Tags: cygwin, putty, iterm

iTerm for the mac has an awesome feature which allows you to ctrl-click on a filename in the terminal.  (i.e. from an ls or find etc), and the terminal will attempt to launch that file using the default application for the given file's type.

I'm familiar with various ways of opening a file from cygwin using a command, but am more interested if anyone knows of a method to mouse click to open a file.

Was wondering if anyone has seen/used such a feature in cygwin/putty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is implemented in the Mintty terminal along with a lot of other nice features so use that instead of the default cygwin one, you should already have it, if you don't download it from [here](https://code.google.com/p/mintty/).

Comment: +1. you could also grab the mintty package during the cygwin setup process.  if you haven't run cygwin's setup.exe in a while, i'd suggest you do so.  after running it for the first time in about a year, it automatically switched my default terminal to mintty.

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  I've been using console2 to run cygwin, but didn't realize the default has this behavour.  Will swap back to default cygwin.